# Postman and laravel delete api

Tags: laravel, api, postman

I am trying to make laravel api, getting request is all working fine but when I use delete request, it show this 
[image]

Please help , what can I do for this.

And this is in my web.php,

`Route::delete('article/{id}','ArticleController@destroy');`

And in ArticleController

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $article=Article::FindOrFail($id);
    if($article->delete()){
        return new ArticleResources($article);
    }
}
```

Comment: there is nothing you passed from postman

Comment: what should I pass for laravel delete route?

Comment: can you provide your delete api code ?

Comment: ok I am editing my question and adding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**API routes should be placed in the api.php and not web.php**

The problem with placing API routes within web.php is that those routes uses web middleware that includes stuff like CSRF protection.

Your postman image doesn't really help, but I can see you get the "Page expired" title, and I assume the problem is CSRF.

So the easiest fix to this problem is to place your API routes in api.php. 
Routes here is prefixed with 'api/' so in this case the new url would be something like:

```
DELETE | http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/article/2
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @joakim-lien answer, you'll face another problem using Postman.

> HTML forms do not support PUT, PATCH or DELETE actions. So, when
>   defining PUT, PATCH or DELETE routes that are called from an HTML
>   form, you will need to add a hidden _method field to the form. The
>   value sent with the _method field will be used as the HTTP request
>   method

source: [Form Method Spoofing - Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#form-method-spoofing)

This is only related to HTML forms and Postman requests, so, if you want to make a DELETE request, you'll need to do a POST request and add a "_method" field set to "DELETE"

[image]

Comment: well you can easily use x-www-form-urlencoded to fix that via postman, or when you  curl set the header application/x-www-form-urlencoded problem solved ..